# Problems implicitly casting a signed long with bitshift into an unsigned 8 bit value

Tags: c, casting, pic, xc8

I'm having a problem with incorrect uint8 values after passing a signed long to a function. You can see the spikes where an overflow(?) has occurred in the raw data values on the right hand axis

[image]

I'm writing this for PIC using MPLABX 5.0 and the XC8 compiler. A simplified version of my code is below:

```
int16_t ADCOutput[6];
signed long ADCOutputAvg[6];
uint8_t USARTRxLSB = 6;

void MOVING_AVERAGE_ADC(void)                                       
{
        READ_ADC();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; ++i)                            
        {
            ADCOutputAvg[i] = (ADCOutputAvg[i]*4) - ADCOutputAvg[i];
            ADCOutputAvg[i] += ADCOutput[i];
            ADCOutputAvg[i] = ADCOutputAvg[i] /4;


        }
SERIAL_WRITE(0x45,(ADCOutputAvg[(USARTRxLSB-1)]>>8), (ADCOutputAvg[(USARTRxLSB-1)]));
}
```

SERIAL_WRITE is the function:

```
    void SERIAL_WRITE(uint8_t Control, uint8_t MSB, uint8_t LSB)
{
    uint8_t Checksum = 0;
    Checksum = NextHeader ^ Control ^ MSB ^ LSB;            
    EUSART1_Write(NextHeader);                          
    EUSART1_Write(Control);                             
    EUSART1_Write(MSB);                                
    EUSART1_Write(LSB);                                 
    EUSART1_Write(Checksum);                                
    if(NextHeader == 0x5A)                              
    {
        NextHeader = 0xA5;                              
    }
    else
    {
        NextHeader = 0x5A;          
    }

}
```

I have managed to fix it by modifying it as follows:

```
int16_t ADCOutput[6];
signed long ADCOutputAvg[6];
uint8_t USARTRxLSB = 6;
int16_t ADCOutputAvgHolder[6];

void MOVING_AVERAGE_ADC(void)                                       
{
        READ_ADC();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; ++i)                            
        {
            ADCOutputAvg[i] = (ADCOutputAvg[i]*4) - ADCOutputAvg[i];
            ADCOutputAvg[i] += ADCOutput[i];
            ADCOutputAvg[i] = ADCOutputAvg[i] /4;
            ADCOutputAvgHolder[i] = (int16_t) ADCOutputAvg[i];

        }
SERIAL_WRITE(0x45,(ADCOutputAvgHolder[(USARTRxLSB-1)]>>8), (ADCOutputAvgHolder[(USARTRxLSB-1)]));
}
```

This now gives the following output:

[image]

The problem is, I don't understand how it has fixed it. In the first instance I have a 32 bit signed integer (which is only ever 16 bits max; it had to go into a 32 bit due to the multiplication on it, but this is later negated with division), which is bitshifted eight right and then implicitly cast into a uint8_t.

The second version has a 32 bit integer, which is explicitly cast into an int16_t, which is then bitshifted eight right and then implicitly cast into a uint8_t. What is different in these methods that give different results?

Comment: A note from the MPLAB documentation on shifting signed values:

If the operand is SIGNED, a shift right performs an ARITHMETIC shift right, in which the vacant bits are filled with whatever the value of the most significant bit was before the shift. This is done to perform a sign extend when working with signed binary values

Comment: shifting signed numbers is a can of worms. divide by 256.

Comment: The documentation would seem to indicate that there wouldn't be problem with the right shift. There is the same 8 bit shift happening with the signed 16 bit which is working, yet with the signed 32 bit it's not...

Comment: Is `SERIAL_WRITE()` properly declared before  `MOVING_AVERAGE_ADC()` calls it?

Comment: Why does the "fixed" one change `USARTRxLSB = 7` to `USARTRxLSB = 6`?

Comment: @chux, I've edited to change both to 6. In the full code USARTRxLSB is read in from a serial input (after validating the value). I've just used 6 as an example here. SERIAL_WRITE is indeed properly defined prior

Comment: Andy, "You can see the spikes where an overflow(?) has occurred in the raw data values on the right hand axis" ---> To be clear, the ADC is the red (hard to see) or the white?  As red, the problem is certainly on some ADC value near 16K which hints to an issue with  `*4`.  You mentioned valid ADC values, good, but what range of values occur?  If ADC is 0 to 64K-1 or so, I'd stick with unsigned math for the conditioning.  Yet I still do not see the code fault - I smell a compiler bug.  (Oh, is SERIAL_WRITE a macro? - if so, please post).

Comment: Why compute a rolling average? If I'm understanding this right, you take six sensor readings all at once. Why not average them the normal way?

Comment: I cannot see what the code you posted accomplishes but whatever it does it is NOT A MOVING AVERAGE. Should you like to see code that does a moving average of ADC readings using a PIC please specify the target part number you need an example for.

Comment: Readings are for separate channels. It IS a moving average, just an exponentially weighted one.

Comment: @chux It is indeed the red line. I've edited my post to include a snapshot of when it is working - you see values are around 16140. ADCOutput is -32768 to 32767. I've also included the full SERIAL_WRITE functon

Comment: Why not work with a union?

Comment: The code you posted evaluates this expression: `Fo = ( (Fo * 4 - Fo) + Fi ) / 4` There are issues when this is evaluated using integer arithmetic. When `Fi-Fo` is `> 0` and `< 4` then `Fo` does not change, when `Fi-Fo` is `< 0` and `> -4` then `F0` decrements by 1. I do not know what kind of filter this is but it's not any kind of moving average I'm familiar with.